# Android Dev | Tweet a string

Tags: android, string, twitter, send

In my project, I have to send tweet. But in every source I read, a tweet sending page opens; user enters his words and sends. I want to tweet **a string I already have**.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: The only difference between sending what the user types in and your own string is where the string comes from. This should be a trivial change to any of the examples that you have read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Twitter's [REST API V1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). This allows you to do myriad tasks through simple HTTP commands such as GET/POST. You're going to have to do some reading if you're not familiar with HTTP commands and/or json/xml (Twitter usual requires whatever you're POSTing to be in json or xml), but it's not too difficult.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTTP and json yet. And the more important is I don't have time for getting familiar with them. I have to close this project until tomorrow 10:00 AM (GTM+2)